# How can I find users with consecutive values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query with the following result

```
ID      Date            result 
xxx3614 2017-02-01  n   
xxx3614 2017-02-06  n   
xxx4522 2017-02-06  n   
xxx5516 2017-02-02  n   
xxx5516 2017-02-04  n   
xxx5516 2017-02-06  n   
xxx9061 2017-02-02  n   
xxx9061 2017-02-04  n   
xxx9061 2017-02-06  y   
xxx9061 2017-02-06  n
```

I am looking for the users which have a result of n consecutively 3 times. SO in the result above, the query on top of this should only give me xxx5516 user
How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to use `lag()` or `lead()`:

```
select distinct id
from (select t.*, lead(result) over (partition by id order by date) as result_1,
             lead(result, 2) over (partition by id order by date) as result_2
      from t
     ) t
where result = 'n' and result_1 = 'n' and result_2 = 'n'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a window function with a range argument to check the past 2 consecutive results:

```
SELECT * from (
SELECT ID, date, result, 
SUM(case when result = 'n' then 1 else 0 end)) 
    OVER (PARTITION BY ID 
            ORDER BY date 
            ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) result_prev_sum
FROM table
) x
WHERE x.result_prev_sum = 3
```

If you want only the third consecutive result, and no more, use UNBOUNDED PRECEDING instead of BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW.

Answer (score 0):

select distinct id from table

where count(result)= 3;